# Not able to create a Xamarin-component for android Source code

Tags: android, xamarin, msbuild, nuget

• I have used the command

```
xamarin-component.exe package C:\cmp\AndroidComponent\component
```

for creating Xamarin component.While building the Sample android project, it is showing the below error. (I have used the command xamarin-component.exe package C:\cmp\AndroidComponent\component -verbose to display the error message in detail).

Error message:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets(155,2):
>   error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   "MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0" were not found. To resolve this, install
>   the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your
>   application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK
>   or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved
>   from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of
>   reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly
>   targeted for the framework you intend.
>   [C:\cmp\AndroidComponent\component\samples\App17\VidyoClientAndroid\VidyoClientAndroid.csproj]

Note:

I am able to create a Xamarin component for iOS source code successfully.
• While creating the Xamarin component for Android source code, internally msbuild.exe is getting called from **64 bit folder**(C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin**amd64**\msbuild.exe "/p:Configuration=Release" "C:\cmp\AndroidComponent\component\samples\App17\App17.sln"...). 
• Build is successful when msbuild.exe is called from path: “C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe”(**32 bit**) explicitly while building the android project explicity.

Comment: You could read this : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96171/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-monoandroid-version-v1-0-were-not-found

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue; you were close to the right answer, and the forums had the correct one.

First lets look at the portion of code that is erroring (Xamarin.Android.Common.targets; in the newer versions of Xamarin this code is much further down):

```
<Target Name="_GetReferenceAssemblyPaths">
<GetReferenceAssemblyPaths
        TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier),Version=v1.0"
        RootPath="$(TargetFrameworkRootPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="ReferenceAssemblyPaths" PropertyName="_XATargetFrameworkDirectories" />
</GetReferenceAssemblyPaths>
```

The most important part here is the

```
$(TargetFrameworkRootPath)
```

When NuGet is ran via the command line we see that it is using the 64bit MSBuild Executable:

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.

(You correctly identified this yourself above) but just to be clear for anyone following along.

When you use the 64bit version of MSBuild `$(TargetFrameworkRootPath)` gets defined as `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework` However Xamarin does not install any of the Framework Utilities to that directory; instead everything lives in the x86 version here `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework`

When you read online a ton of people get this problem solved by installing Visual Studio 2017; but that is a red-herring it only works because it causes NuGet to use MSBuild 15 which ships with Visual Studio 2017 which apparently is not affected by this bug.

There are a few ways to fix this issue:

1. Tell NuGet to use the x86 MSBuild when you Restore using the optional -MSBuildPath argument as described here [How Can I Tell NuGet What MSBuild Executable to Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822757/how-can-i-tell-nuget-what-msbuild-executable-to-use/49823570#49823570)
2. Upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 to get MSBuild 15
3. <strike>Define `$(TargetFrameworkRootPath)` to be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework`; this can be done however you please, the biggest hammer is to set it as an environment variable in the environment prior to execution. Note this will probably cause a bunch of unintended side-affects if you're not careful.</strike> <- DON'T DO THIS, Even as suggested in the forms.