# Error while creating xamarin-component for android

Tags: xamarin

I have used the command

xamarin-component.exe package C:\cmp\AndroidComponent\component 
for creating Xamarin component.While building the Sample android project, it is showing the below error. (I have used the command xamarin-component.exe package C:\cmp\AndroidComponent\component -verbose to display the error message in detail).

Error message:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets(155,2): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework "MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [C:\cmp\AndroidComponent\component\samples\App17\VidyoClientAndroid\VidyoClientAndroid.csproj]

Note:

I am able to create a Xamarin component for iOS source code successfully. • While creating the Xamarin component for Android source code, internally msbuild.exe is getting called from 64 bit folder(C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin**amd64**\msbuild.exe "/p:Configuration=Release" "C:\cmp\AndroidComponent\component\samples\App17\App17.sln"...). • Build is successful when msbuild.exe is called from path: “C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe”(32 bit) explicitly while building the android project explicity.

Comment: Have you found this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96171/the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-monoandroid-version-v1-0-were-not-found ? Maybe it helps. Are you using VS17?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question; see my answer there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350208/not-able-to-create-a-xamarin-component-for-android-source-code 

I am unable to close this duplicate because my answer does not yet have an upvote.