# How Can I Tell NuGet What MSBuild Executable to Use?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

NuGet apparently has some logic to determine what MSBuild Executable to use. Is there a way to override this behavior? Or at least a way to tell it to use the x86 MSBuild instead of x64?

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [command-line documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-restore), you can specify `-MSBuildPath` or `-MSBuildVersion` on the command line.

> `MSBuildPath` (4.0+) Specifies the path of MSBuild to use with the
>   command, taking precedence over -MSBuildVersion.
>
> `MSBuildVersion`  (3.2+)
>   Specifies the version of MSBuild to be used with this command.
>   Supported values are 4, 12, 14, 15. By default the MSBuild in your
>   path is picked, otherwise it defaults to the highest installed version
>   of MSBuild.

Comment: Thank you @Rainer Sigwald; not sure how I missed the documentation. Helped me fix this issue with the latest Xamarin Installer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350208/not-able-to-create-a-xamarin-component-for-android-source-code/49822690#49822690

Comment: But this command-line option only affects current command, it will not change the default msbuild detection. I can't add this option every time when I'm trying to restore a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The msbuild version used by nuget command line on mono is hard coded:

Cf source code https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f24bad0668193ce21a1db8cabd1ce95ba509c7f0/src/NuGet.Clients/NuGet.CommandLine/MsBuildUtility.cs

The offending method is `GetMsBuildFromMonoPaths(...)`

There is no env var to override it. It's called "auto detection" lol.

A solution is to move away the `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0` folder, install msbuild 16.0 using `dotnet-install.sh` method (use version 5.0.402 for msbuild 16), and create a symbolic link from `dotnet/sdk/$netcoreversion` to the hard coded path `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0`

Comment: Might be worth opening an issue with NuGet they are usually pretty responsive?

Comment: @aolszowka well on this one they are not. The issue is already open.

Comment: can you link the GitHub issue?

Comment: @aolszowka https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9222